# Input text next to button

Tags: html

I can't seem to get the submit button next to Choose us 5# What am i doing wrong? Everything i have tried will either get it sitting above the Choose is 5# or throws the upload context out of alignment.

I have edited code to make it easier to read and format.

Still struggling with a solution.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Website Text</div>
<div class="panel-body">

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
<form data-toggle="validator">

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">

<label form="contactEmail" class="control-label">Select your contact email</label>
<input type="text" name="headerh4"class="form-control" id="headerh4" value="<?php echo $result['headerh4']?>"  required><br />

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">

<label form="chooseus4" class="control-label">Choose us #4</label>
<input type="text" name="chooseus4"class="form-control" id="chooseus4" value="<?php echo $result['chooseus4']?>"  required> <br />

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">

<label form="chooseus5" class="control-label">Choose us #</label>
<input type="text" name="chooseus5"class="form-control" id="chooseus5" value="<?php echo $result['chooseus5']?>"  required>



<input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit" value="Submit">

</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">

<label form="companylogo" class="control-label">Company Logo</label>
<form method="POST" action="landingpage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myimagelogo" id="i_file" /><br />
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-md" type="submit" name="submit_imagelogo" value="Upload">
</form>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your code in this manner

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-md-8">
...
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry about that.